GPG 2 hangs when given the wrong passphrase
When I use GPG to decrypt a packed and encrypted backup, I plan to use a script that loops over old passphrases so I don't have to sweat rolling them regularly. Testing this, however, gpg never exits after attempting a key and printing gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key, so I can never attempt another. I'm hoping it's just some kind of typo I can't see.
The command I'm running is:
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.4

gpg --debug-all --pinentry-mode loopback --batch --yes --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-file ~/.curpass --decrypt /mnt/data-disk/backups/series-2024-10-01/2024-10-01_07-00-02_full/data.xbstream.zs.aes256 > /mnt/data-disk/backups/series-2024-10-01/2024-10-01_07-00-02_full/data.xbstream.zs 2> log.txt

log.txt:
gpg: reading options from '[cmdline]'
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] start
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_open (/mnt/data-disk/backups/series-2024-10-01/2024-10-01_07-00-02_full/data.xbstream.zs.aes256) not cached
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: open '/mnt/data-disk/backups/series-2024-10-01/2024-10-01_07-00-02_full/data.xbstream.zs.aes256' desc=file_filter(fd) fd=4
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=3 length=13 (parse.../../g10/mainproc.c.1560)
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: DBG: free_packet() type=3
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: push 'block_filter'
gpg: DBG: iobuf chain: 1.1 'block_filter' filter_eof=0 start=0 len=0
gpg: DBG: iobuf chain: 1.0 'file_filter(fd)' filter_eof=0 start=17 len=8192
gpg: DBG: init block_filter 0x000060965f395d90
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=18 length=0 (new_ctb) (parse.../../g10/mainproc.c.1560)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
gpg: DBG: free_packet() type=18
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)

These lines then repeat until I cancel execution.
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.1: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
``

